# memcache and sessions, don't work

Tags: magento-1.8, sessions, memcached

I used memcache for sessions but can not login to both of frontend and backend in mg1810

before this, I did use redis for sessions and now want to use memcache instead of redis

Also did FLUSHALL in redis-cli, memcache service is running and local.xml set to ...

```
<config>
<global>

    <session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
    <session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>

</global>
</config>
```

Comment: Does php -m list memcache*d*?

Comment: @Melvyn : Great post man, thank you, my problem solved. please add your answer in main page please to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento uses the **memcached** php extension to communicate with Memcache, but won't warn you if you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the 'cache' tag

```
<session_save><![CDATA[memcache]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://localhost:11213?persistent=0&amp;weight=2&amp;timeout=10&amp;retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path> 
<cache>
    <backend><![CDATA[memcached]]></backend>
    <auto_refresh_fast_cache>0</auto_refresh_fast_cache>
    <default_priority>10</default_priority>
    <memcached>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                <port><![CDATA[11212]]></port>
                <persistent><![CDATA[0]]></persistent>
            </server>
        </servers>
    </memcached>
</cache>
```

For sessions in redis:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <!-- other configuration nodes -->
        <session_save>db</session_save>
        <redis_session>                       <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>            <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>             <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>            <!-- This is the Redis connection timeout, not the locking timeout -->
            <persistent></persistent>         <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. -->
            <db>2</db>                        <!-- Redis database number; protection from accidental loss is improved by using a unique DB number for sessions -->
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  <!-- Set to 0 to disable compression (recommended when suhosin.session.encrypt=on); known bug with strings over 64k: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/18 -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              <!-- gzip, lzf or snappy -->
            <log_level>4</log_level>               <!-- 0 (emergency: system is unusable), 4 (warning; additional information, recommended), 5 (notice: normal but significant condition), 6 (info: informational messages), 7 (debug: the most information for development/testing) -->
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 <!-- maximum number of processes that can wait for a lock on one session; for large production clusters, set this to at least 10% of the number of PHP processes -->
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       <!-- seconds to wait for a session lock in the frontend; not as critical as admin -->
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    <!-- Bots get shorter session lifetimes. 0 to disable -->
        </redis_session>
        <!-- other configuration nodes -->
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: No, I deleted them only here, I use redis cache

Comment: You run Magento CE or EE?

Comment: Magento CE version

Comment: check edited answer...that's how I set session in redis. Here is a good article http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/using-redis-cache-backend-and-session-storage-in-magento/

Comment: Dear, I know how to set redis for session but I want to use memcache for session and redis for cache, they are different!

Comment: Have you tried setting persistent to 0 in <session_save_path><![CDATA[tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=2&timeout=10&retry_interval=10]]></session_save_path>?